# SUMIFS with INDEX/MATCH and Dynamic ranges

Tags: google-sheets

Here is the spreadsheet of data and desired result:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13tXrlZQK0bXlA2EhGA-CJEXAEdfxyvAWvqwflqty-GA/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, I wish to create a drop-down dependent result that is able to SUM the count (by month) and favorites (and potentially AVG the percentages) from a date range.

The only caveat is the date range is in D/M/YYYY format and I wish the drop-down to be month. So this will need an EOMONTH formula.

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Agreed. Without a link to a spreadsheet with test data already in it, the volunteer contributors here would have to start their own new spreadsheet and hand-enter your data before even considering a solution. And that will be a deterrent to many. In addition, as it stands, we don't know where the results will go, what sheet names are, whether your real data set includes more sections, etc. Help us to help you: share a link to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Previous comments are right, remember to always try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13tXrlZQK0bXlA2EhGA-CJEXAEdfxyvAWvqwflqty-GA/edit?usp=sharing

My sincere apologies. Here is the data and the expected result. I'll update the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of helper columns.

The formulas that I used to achieve your results were:

`count`:

```
=SUMIFS(F5:F9,E5:E9,G11,D5:D9,F13)+SUMIFS(J5:J9,I5:I9,G11,D5:D9,F13)
```

`favorite`:

```
=SUMIFS(G5:G9,E5:E9,G11,D5:D9,F13)+SUMIFS(K5:K9,I5:I9,G11,D5:D9,F13)
```

`pct. fav avg`:

```
=IF(G11="Blue",AVERAGEIFS(L5:L9,I5:I9,G11,D5:D9,F13),AVERAGEIFS(H5:H9,E5:E9,G11,D5:D9,F13))
```

There are 2 helper columns used: `color` and `month`.

[image]

I'll attach the sample sheet I used for testing, you can just hide the helper columns.

[Test Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kCeDWCNtSbdzhCg643YLrIounYJPHr1K_QcpXcSnLdk/edit?usp=sharing)